# Kotlin-Native cinterop Updating a Struc field from C

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I am using kotlin-native and have to pass a pointer to a struc to a C function. My "Kotlin Stub" has the signature of fun SET_SM_REFS_INDEX(index: Int, thisObject: CValuesRef?).

On the native side the code wants to hold a pointer to 'thisObject' and wants to update a field in the structure possibly in another thread. Lets call that field an integer "thisObject->myUpdate" for example.

Right now I try to create an object using  var AA = cValue<..> and try to call the function as
SET_SM_REFS_INDEX(0, AA).  There are no compilation errors.  However I notice my field "AA.update" never gets updated and always stays at 0.

Reading documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mapping-struct-union-types-from-c.html it says something about maybe using kotlinx.cinterop.NativePlacement" but does not go into detail.

I can see that cValue is probably the wrong thing to pass as it has byValue semantics.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think i found the answer.  For my Example:

Instead of having

var AA = cValue<..>

one needs

var AA = nativeHeap.alloc<..>()

where ".." is the C struct type from your Klib stub. then the call would be

SET_SM_REFS_INDEX(0, AA.ptr)

note the ".ptr" and remember to somewhere down the line to explicitly free the memory

nativeHeap.free(AA)

I have to use nativeHeap becasue i am using the C struct in a scope that stays around, kinda 'globalish'.  There is another way to use alloc more 'locally' with memScope{} and with memScope you are not on the hook to explicilty free the memory.

Hope this helps someone